# Adding multiple items to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema with

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    skills: [{ name: { type: String, unique: true }, level: { type: Number } }],
```

and I am trying, after getting an array of objects from the client, to add all of them at once under a user in MongoDB

my old implementation when it was only an array is this one below. I have no idea how to go about it now tho. Could anyone help me?

```
const { email } = session;
const { skill } = req.body;
if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });

        const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
            { email },
            { skills: [...user.skills, { name: skill }] }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const { email } = session;
// object from the client
const { skills } = req.body;
if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {

        const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
            { email },
            { $set: {skills} }
        );
```

the best is getting the array correctly formatted from front-end, if not use a map before call findOneAndUpdate

Comment: So I tried till now and I couldn't manage to spread the existing array, and add the new elements to it with $set, but I found $addToSet fixed that for me, So I basically did 

`const { skill: skills } = req.body;
 if (req.method === 'POST') {
  try {
   const user = await User.findOne({ email });

   const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { email },
    { $addToSet: { skills } }
   );`

Your answer tho put me on the right track, and probably there is a way to do it with $set that I couldn't manage to find. Thank you

Comment: nice to hear it man!